# JQuery DataTables column visibility toggle reduces table width everytime

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, datatables

I am using [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html) in my rails application. I have implemented the functionality to show/hide first column on `Click` event of a `button` using following JS:

```
// HTML body
<button id='show-hide' title='Hide logos'>«</button>

// Javascript
table = $('.mytable').DataTable();

$('#show-hide').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var column = table.column(0);
  column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  if(column.visible()) {
    $(this).text("«");
    $(this).attr("title","Hide logos");
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).text("»");
    $(this).attr("title","Show logos");
  }
});
```

Every time I click on the button, it toggles the column visibility, but, reduces the table width to few pixels (5px or so). And it continues reducing it on every click.

I found in Style debugger window that new reduced `width` is being set on every click as follows:

```
element.style {
   width: 1080px;
}
```

Any help ?

Comment: have you got a class that sets the width on the table?

Comment: Yes, there is one but that does not set any width for table. Although that sets width per table-row as tr { min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; }

Comment: But I have tried removing that tr styling, it does not solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried adding `width:100%` to the table class?

Comment: Yes, that initially sets the element.style { width:100% }, but after first click on button that is again set to reduced width (e.g. 1020px)